# Rails 3 ActiveRecord sum of a model for each associated model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have 2 models

```
Category
- id
- name
```

and

```
Transaction
 - id
 - category_id
 - amount
```

I want to find the sum of all transactions for each category. 
I know I can get a list of caterogies and then get the sum for all the transactions with the category_id but it will do 20+ queries.

Is there a way to do it all in one query?

Edit: I want to end up with a list of [[category1, sum], [category2, sum]].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Transaction.group(:category_id).sum(:amount)
```

This will return a hash similar to this:

```
{CATEGORY_ID => SUM_OF_TRANSACTIONS, ....}
```

or

```
{1 => 100.0, 2 => 350.0, etc.}
```

To get the actual `Category` names:

```
Transaction.includes(:category).group("categories.name").sum(:amount)
# => {"Category1" => 100.0, ...}
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to get the category names or do I have to query that separately?

Comment: @Dylan Markow, cool! I thought about raw sql here, to return whole `Category` object with additional `transaction_sum` attribute

Comment: Only problem here can be if category name is not uniq (in big trees there can be the same categories with different parents)

Answer (score 0):

```
@category.transactions.sum(:amount)
```

**UPD 1**

you can share some job with Ruby:

```
Category.includes(:transactions).map{|c| [c.name, c.transactions.inject(0){|sum, t| sum += t.amount}]}
```

Comment: this will give me the sum of transactions for 1 category. Is there a way to do the same for all of them.

Comment: The idea of using Ruby for some of it will definitely work for a small dataset without any noticeable speed decrease, but it will become painfully slow on a large dataset since it needs to iterate over every single transaction.